# Clipping a road layer by using region attributes

Tags: qgis, clip, fields-attributes, features

I've been trying to **clip a road layer** into several layers by using **region polygons**. So in detail: I've got a layer with all roads of Germany and a second layer with all states and regions of Germany. And now I'm trying to divide this road layer by German states and regions and save them as shapefiles named after that region. Meaning: **Loading this new shapefile only contains the roads of one region.** It only works for one feature at a time, selecting the one region and going into the geoprocessing tools and clip the roads layer.

Is there any easy one-step-way to do it for all features? I could not find anything similar in the forum, as I don't know where and what to search for exactly.

If you need a more specific explanation, I'll do my best.

Comment: unasked for advice: don't. structured data is fundamental, but having a ton of *shapefile* sets at its root is a waste of effort IMO; having a file system based sub-structure of semantically linked data in times of *GeoPackage* (or *SQLite*) for file based data or PostGIS for DB storage and analysis cannot even be justified anymore as being a matter of taste (compatibility, maybe, but not in an OGC/FOSS driven ecosystem). excuse my ranting...

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Multi Clip](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/MultiClip/)** plugin. It clips a layer by each polygon in another layer.

[image]

For sample process above, *Roads* layer is clipped by each *States* polygon and saved as `Road1.shp, Road2.shp, ...`.

**PS**: The plugin is experimental, therefore you have to check `Show also experimental plugins` in  *Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins > Setting* tab.